# I3 Mega, PROBE_MANUALLY with ABL

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling

I created some Marlin versions for Creality and Anycubic printers. Now I have a problem and want to ask if someone can help me, give some tips or something else.

Printer: i3 Mega Anycubic
I use the 2.0.bugfixes and took a configuration example from 2.0.8.1

The firmware works, but the movement/travel from XY is very slow when I go to the next probe_point.

Homing works great.

Only the probe_manually does not work.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Try Disable Auto bed
2. set up `XY_PROBE_FEEDRATE` (100*60) higher
3. set `HOMING_FEEDRATE_MM_M` higher
4. disable `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR`

Nothing helps

It looks like the `xy_probe_feedrate` would not be interpreted...

Comment: Does [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/13999) answer your question? Note that parameter names change over time `SPEED` now seems to be `FEEDRATE`, see [`Marlin/src/inc/SanityCheck.h`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/ee26fd0e0559d7f2d86b11b5552eaf9c9ff3174c/Marlin/src/inc/SanityCheck.h).

Comment: @oscar Thank for your answer. I think it doesn't help, because i already use the new name "Feedrate" and not the old declaration "Speed". I hope i understand you.